# Video Straming on APP

Tags: django, django-views, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I have an raspberry pi 2 board  with camera, my django server and my mobile app. I want to start the raspberry camera and do live streaming on my mobile app through the django server. Is there any possible way to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think yes with [UV4L](http://linux-projects.org) and WebRTC. Just take the HTML5 page from the UV4L Streaming Server and put it in your Web Page/App.